# Integrate web app with card present credit card device

Tags: web-applications, pci-compliance, pos

I'm looking to integrate the customer POS interface in my Web/Mobile Angular 2+ app with a credit card device that accepts chip/swipe card present transactions.

Below is the simplest diagram of the flow I'm wanting.

[image: Transaction Flow]

My Main Goals:

- Chip or Magnetic Card Swipe
- Avoid "My App" from having to be PCI Compliant
- Associate My App pyament db record with CC transaction ID
- Do this in realtime (Without having to poll the CC Processor/Merchant for Transaction)

I want to avoid having to be PCI Complaint myself and leave that up a 3rd party system. All I want to do is associate a payment in my system to a transaction ID of the processor/merchant after a credit card swipe.

I'm mostly concerned with doing this through a Desktop (Web version of my App), where it communicates with the POS Device (In some form or another).

I don't think this capability actually exists the way I have it drawn out, and am just trying to figure it out.
Right now the closest solution is to integrate a Mobile swiper, which isn't desktop, or build a whole custom PCI Complaint system to communicate with a swiper.

Comment: I know that [this device](https://idtechproducts.com/products/countertop/sredkey/) can be plugged into a USB port and generates encrypted card data in a form that a web browser can receive. That company may have other devices that support chip which may be able to do the same. You’d still need something to handle sending that data, though.

Answer (score 0):

I found a 3rd party solution that basically handles the transaction through REST API calls to a specific device id, where I can send a request to the terminal through a API network call and it waits for a response of the transaction data or error. I haven't actually integrated it yet but am going to try it out.

https://www.expinet.io/

Comment: Where you successful, Scot? I am looking at something similar. In my case I just want to interface my Angular Web Application with a POS MSCR, get the track data from the card and then send it to the PSP via a backend service. Would this Expinet API work for that?